# Python interactive REPL inside a with statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

From an python interactive session, is there a way to enter a REPL loop inside a with statement?

Normally, a with statement is executed as a single block

```
>>>
>>> with app.app_context():
>>> ...   # Normally this is executed as a single block, all at once
```

I'd like to be able to run code in an interactive session, in the context.

```
>>>
>>> with app.app_context():
>>> # do stuff here in a REPL loop
```

Comment: What do you mean  by repl loop?

Comment: Is this in a script that you want to temporarily turn interactive, or are you already in an interactive session, where you want to run statements in a `with` context interactively without needing to finish the whole `with` block first?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham REPL = Read Eval Print Loop https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop

Comment: @00500005, I know what a repl is, I meant in the context of your question

Comment: @PadraicCunningham clarified context of the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't exactly mimic a `with` statement, but you can probably get close by calling `app.app_context().__enter__()` manually.

This won't `__exit__` automatically if there's an exception, but otherwise it should work the same (you might need to call `__exit__` yourself when you're done, I'm not sure what exactly that context manager does).

Comment: A context manager calls `__exit__` for any exit condition, and can do things like recover or change exceptions. But for my purposes, that's not that useful

Comment: Yeah, that's why I mentioned calling `__exit__` yourself. It might not matter though, depending on what the `app_context` context manager does (its `__exit__` method may do little or nothing).

Answer (score 0):

A fully-functioning REPL for very simple inputs (i.e. no variable declarations) with a `contextmanager` in Python 2.7:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys 
class app(object):
    @contextmanager
    def app_context(self):
       sys.stdout.write(">>> ")
       yield raw_input()

with app().app_context() as output:
   while True:
       print eval(output)
       output = app().app_context().__enter__()
```

This will need some work to handle anything more sophisticated - that `eval` is an eyesore, and there's no good way to break the loop short of ^C - but it should work.